# react-native: 'RCTFatalException: No script URL provided

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native, react-native-ios

I already created a fresh react-native project, and it's working fine on android(debug/release) and ios(debug).

But when i switched to release scheme as described by [Facebook docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html)
it crash on startup and throw the following exception:

> Make sure the packager is running or you have embedded a JS bundle in
> your application bundle.unsanitizedScriptURLString:((null)) 2017-01-17
> 21:59:18.720641 XXXX[332:53718] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
> exception 'RCTFatalException: No script URL provided.

Any idea about the cause of this issue?!

**xcode:8.0** and **react-native:0.40.0**

Answer (score 2):

I am answering my own question.

My problem has been solved by generating **jsBundle** using this command:

`react-native bundle --dev false --assets-dest ./ios --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle`